# Where is the high-level charts in bokeh's last version (1.0.3)?

Tags: charts, bokeh

I hava a quick question:

I see that you have the high-level charts in the version 0.11.0:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html

But I can't find the same topic in the last version (1.0.3)? Did bokeh team remove it?

I have been working on adapting histograms to my project but can't find the histograms section in the last version?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `bokeh.charts` API was deprecated and scheduled to be removed in version 1.0 several *years* ago. However, even that schedule was also eventually accelerated, due to lack of interest and better alternatives. It has been completely gone from the project since late 2017.

For very high level APIs on top of Bokeh, consider [Chartify](https://github.com/spotify/chartify) or [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/). Or just create histograms directly with the stable `bokeh.plotting` API. e.g.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df
from numpy import histogram

p = figure(plot_height=300)

hist, edges = histogram(df.hp, density=True, bins=20)
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], line_color="white")

show(p)
```

[image]